# Magento 2: zend pdf anchor link not show in pdf file

Tags: magento2.3.2, pdf, link, zend

I am using below code to show hyperlink in pdf file but link is not showing.Drawtext method works fine.It means hyperlink code is not working

```
$pdf = new \Zend_Pdf();
                        $pdf->pages[] = $pdf->newPage(\Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4);
                        $page = $pdf->pages[0]; // this will get reference to the first page.
                        $style = new \Zend_Pdf_Style();
$target = \Zend_Pdf_Action_URI::create('http://example.com', true);

             $annotation = \Zend_Pdf_Annotation_Link::create($x+250, $this->y-20, $x+400, $this->y-20, $target);
             $page->attachAnnotation($annotation);
             $page->drawLine($x+250, $this->y-10, $x+350, $this->y - 10);
```

In my above code line is showing but hyperlink not showing

Answer (score 2):

```
$target = \Zend_Pdf_Action_URI :: create( $baseUrl );
$annotation = \Zend_Pdf_Annotation_Link :: create( 35, $this->y + 10, 100, $this->y - 5, $target );
$page->attachAnnotation( $annotation );
```

above code will add an area of rectangle where u can click and it ll redirect.

35 is x1 point

100 is x2

this->y  is y1
this->y - 5 is y2 in my case

if you want to add a text at that rectangle

```
$page->drawText($baseUrlText, 35, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
```

here it ll add a text in that area
and therefor it become clickable

Comment: Thanks @bashid it worked!